# Trying to set up OAuth with Ktor, providerLookup problems

Tags: kotlin, oauth, nullpointerexception, ktor

So Im trying to set up OAuth for Kotlin, Ktor. Im trying to follow the [documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/oauth.html)
on but I get stuck on the [config part](https://ktor.io/docs/oauth.html#configure-oauth) on [step 2](https://ktor.io/docs/oauth.html#configure-oauth-provider). When my program runs:

```
call.request.queryParameters["redirectUrl"]!!
```

I get a null point exeption. When running the program in a debugger mode I can see that call/request/queryParameters is not null. So it should be the "redirectUrl" that is not "working".

I have tried to search for what the line is suppose to do but I cant find any explanation of it anywhere. I can only finds its use in this documentation. I assume it is suppose to get some redirecting URLs but I have no clue from where.

What can I do to solve my null point exeption?

Here is my class if it helps

```
package com.example.plugins

import io.ktor.server.auth.*
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.apache.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
import io.ktor.server.sessions.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*

fun Application.configureSecurity() {


val redirects = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
authentication {
    oauth("auth-oauth-google") {
        urlProvider = { "http://localhost:8086/callback" }
        providerLookup = {
            OAuthServerSettings.OAuth2ServerSettings(
                name = "google",
                authorizeUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
                accessTokenUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
                requestMethod = HttpMethod.Post,
                clientId = System.getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"),
                clientSecret = System.getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"),
                defaultScopes = listOf("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"),
                extraAuthParameters = listOf("access_type" to "offline"),
                onStateCreated = { call, state ->
                    redirects[state] = call.request.queryParameters["redirectUrl"]!!
                }
            )
        }
        client = HttpClient(Apache)
    }
}
data class MySession(val count: Int = 0)
install(Sessions) {
    cookie<MySession>("MY_SESSION") {
        cookie.extensions["SameSite"] = "lax"
        cookie.maxAgeInSeconds = 120
        cookie.path = "/testing"
    }
    cookie<UserSession>("USER_SESSION") {
        cookie.extensions["SameSite"] = "lax"
        cookie.maxAgeInSeconds = 120
        cookie.path = "/testingss"
    }


}
routing {
    authenticate("auth-oauth-google") {
        get("login") {
            call.respondRedirect("/callback")
        }

        get("/callback") {
            val principal: OAuthAccessTokenResponse.OAuth2? = call.principal()
            call.sessions.set(UserSession(principal!!.state!!, principal.accessToken))
            val redirect = redirects[principal.state!!]
            call.respondRedirect(redirect!!)
        }
    }
    get("/session/increment") {
        val session = call.sessions.get<MySession>() ?: MySession()
        call.sessions.set(session.copy(count = session.count + 1))
        call.respondText("Counter is ${session.count}. Refresh to increment.")
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to redirect a client to the URL it came from, add the query parameter `redirectUrl` (the actual name doesn't matter but has to be consistent) to the `/login` endpoint. Here are the steps of the flow:

1. Client requests an unprotected endpoint
2. If the session is absent (the client is unauthenticated), the server responds with a redirect to `/login` with a query parameter `redirectUrl`, which contains the requested URL.
3. The `/login` endpoint triggers OAuth2 authentication, and when a `state` is created, the `redirectUrl` is saved to the `redirects` map inside the `onStateCreated` block.
4. The client is redirected by the OAuth2 provider to the callback URL, where the redirect is happening to the previously saved URL.

Here is an example:

```
get("/{path}") {
    val userSession: UserSession? = call.sessions.get()
    if (userSession != null) {
        val userInfo: UserInfo = httpClient.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo") {
            headers {
                append(HttpHeaders.Authorization, "Bearer ${userSession.token}")
            }
        }.body()
        call.respondText("Hello, ${userInfo.name}!")
    } else {
        val redirectUrl = URLBuilder("http://0.0.0.0:8080/login").run {
            parameters.append("redirectUrl", call.request.uri)
            build()
        }
        call.respondRedirect(redirectUrl)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what to do. 
Are you saying that the above get function would solve the problem?

Or is the "add the query parameter redirectUrl to the /login endpoint" that should solve it, I am not quite sure how to do that. Any elaboration or documentation would be apprisiated.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, the handler for the `get("/{path}")` route would solve your problem. In that handler, if there is no session, then a client will be redirected to the `/login` endpoint with a query parameter `redirectUrl`, which contains a requested URL. So the above get function would solve your problem **because** it adds the `redirectUrl` query parameter to the `/login` endpoint by making a redirect.

Comment: Okay. Having problems getting it to compile but then ill put more effort into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by exchanging `call.request.queryParameters["redirectUrl"]!!` with just a normal string, such as `"http://localhost:3000/home"`.

Works as long as you only have the same url you are going to redirect to.

Comment: Yes, this is broken (for some unknown reason) in the example code... not sure why. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The answer given is not addressing the problem. There is NullPointerException when the ktor oauth model example is used.

Also, in the get("/{path}") {} block, for the case when there is a existing session avilable, how do we redirect? If I try to call.respondRedirect(), it again lands into get("/{path}") {} block. This is infinite loop.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34362329)

Comment: @schrom, this is not new qn, but about the answer given.